JavaScript clientWidth misreporting when padding value is percentage
In the example code below the element with class .carousel is set to have width: 500px but the the width reported by clientWidth is 471. I can fix this by setting the padding value of .arrow to a pixel value instead of a percentage and clientWidth then correctly reports 500.  Is this a bug or am I not understanding something?
When .arrow padding is set as a percentage I can't seem to get 500 no matter what JS function I use.
This is in Safari, not tested elsewhere.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {  
  console.log(document.getElementById("width-inspect").offsetWidth);
});
body, html {
    background: black;
}

.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;   
    display: flex; 
}

.carousel-right-box {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 680px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.carousel-content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.arrow {
    padding: 1%;
}
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="carousel-right-box">
     <button class='arrow'> 
     <img src="./images/left-arrow.png">
     </button>
     <div class="carousel">
        <div id="width-inspect" class="carousel-content">

        </div>
     </div>
     <button class='arrow'> 
     <img src="./images/right-arrow.png">
     </button>
  </div>
</div> 




The snippet in your question is giving me 500 on Safari on IOS 16…., iPad. What device and OS are you using?

@AHaworth It seems to on all the desktop browsers (on Mac). Although the snippet here outputs 480.

I converted your code into a reproducible example.
You should add to .carousel { flex-shrink: 0; } or flex: none; so that it does not shrink.


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {  
  console.log(document.getElementById("width-inspect").offsetWidth);
});
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, html {
    background: black;
}

.flex-row {
    flex-direction: row;   
    display: flex; 
}

.carousel-right-box {
    max-width: 1024px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 680px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    flex: none; /* <- */
}

.carousel-content {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.arrow {
    padding: 1%;
}
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="carousel-right-box">
     <button class='arrow'> 
     <img src="./images/left-arrow.png">
     </button>
     <div class="carousel">
        <div id="width-inspect" class="carousel-content">

        </div>
     </div>
     <button class='arrow'> 
     <img src="./images/right-arrow.png">
     </button>
  </div>
</div>




@imvost thanks, any idea why I need to that? Is it expected behaviour. What I don't get is that on my snippet the web inspector gives 499px as the value but JS outputs 480px.
